# Hiding ".txt" extension and loading file names from folder

Tags: c#

I need hide ".txt" extensions in "combobox" and i dont know how.

[image: .txt]

And how i can do that, that files will loaded from actualy addresesr and some folder? Now i using this code:

**Im using this code now:**

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\JD_1609\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\bin\Debug\PCs");
FileInfo[] Files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");

comboBox1.DataSource = Files;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

But if i transfer it to other pc so its will not working right?
So how i can load files from actually addresser?

Comment: How are you displaying the files in your combobox? Instead of displaying the files with the extension, you should display just the names

Comment: So... show how you assign it to the combobox...

Comment: Im using this code now:
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\JD_1609\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\bin\Debug\PCs");
            FileInfo[] Files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");

            comboBox1.DataSource = Files;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

Comment: Do you want your Value to be the full path?  Just the name with extension?

Comment: I need only write file name to combobox without extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the names of a file *without* the extension included you can use the nifty [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method of the `Path` class.

If you want your DataSource to display the name without the extension, but keep the "value" as a `FileInfo`, you can use a little Linq to turn your `FileInfo[]` into a `Dictionary<string, FileInfo>`, then set the display and value member properties appropriately:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(
                           Files.ToDictionary(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name), 
                                              x => x), 
                           null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Remember that a `Dictionary` cannot have duplicate keys.  In your code you grab all the textfiles of a single directory, so even when we strip the extension off we can be certain that there won't be duplicates.  If you *change your query* in a way that would introduce duplicates into the Dictionary, my answer will throw an exception.

If all you need is the display and value to be the filename without extension its even easier:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Files
                           .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name))
                           .ToArray();
```

Comment: When I try use this so its write:
"System.ArgumentException: The Structured DataBinding object receives IList or IListSource as the data source."

Comment: @JD_1609 look at my edited answer

Comment: And now its write error: "Argument 1: Can not convert from System.IO.FileInfo to string." :D
-when i use that easier way

Comment: @JD_1609 sorry, long day.  I just updated.  It should be `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name)` not `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)`

Comment: np, its work now thanks you SOOOOO MUCH! :) <3